# chart looking strange on phone´s browser using chart.js

Tags: javascript, html, charts, chart.js, responsive

I am using chart.js to create my charts. The chart itself looks pretty neat as long as I display it on my PC´s browsers.

As soon as I use my phone´s browser the chart does not look neat anmyore at all, the x-Axis being cut partly. 
I am also using Bootstrap.

My code looks as following:

```
 <div id="TempChart" class="chart-container col-md-8 col-xs-8 col-lg-8 col-sm-8"  style ="position: relative; 40vh; width 80vw">

   <canvas id="chart"></canvas>

</div>
```

Changing it to following did not help:

```
<canvas id="chart" class = "img-responsive"></canvas>
```

I have also added following part in my javascript code for generating the chart.

```
options: {
      animation: {
    duration: 0
}, 
 responsive: true,
```

Does anybody have an idea how to make it look neat on a phone´s browser as well?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To display properly on changing viewport size use

```
options: {
    maintainAspectRatio: false,
```

**Edit:** I found the best experience in a particular case was using the above mentioned but *without*

```
options: {
        responsive: true,
```

so you might wanna try that as well :-)

Comment: It looks nicer indeed, but this also causes the chart to grow according to how many times it is reloaded. Have you experienced the same?

Comment: I experienced the same but think that went away after removing `responsive`. Only other difference in my case was that I had not defined a `width` in `style`.